# Detecting PlusMinus in an expression

Tags: pattern-matching

`FreeQ` and `MemberQ` keep telling me that the expression is incomplete when I want to check if `\[PlusMinus]` is present in an expression. Any ideas for a work around?
Thanks

Comment: Post an example

Comment: Could you give an example expression with [PlusMinus].

Comment: `FreeQ[expression,  _PlusMinus]` or `FreeQ[expression, a_ ±  b_]`?

Comment: Yes kglr, that's it. I was missing underscore before term. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expressions = {±2, ±2 + xyz,  x y z, x PlusMinus[a, b], 3 ± 5}
```

> {±2, xyz + ±2, x y z, x (a ± b),  3 ± 5}

```
FreeQ[#, PlusMinus] & /@ expressions
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

```
FreeQ[#, _PlusMinus] & /@ expressions
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

```
FreeQ[#, PlusMinus[__]] & /@ expressions
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

```
FreeQ[#, ___ ± ___] & /@ expressions
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

```
FreeQ[#, _ ± _] & /@ expressions
```

> {True, True, True, False, False}

Answer (score 1):

For any question like "Detecting ... in an expression", the first thing you should do is look at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of a simple example. In your case, something like:

```
FullForm[a ± b]
```

> PlusMinus[a,b]

would show you that you need to look for the head `PlusMinus`, and not the character $\pm$.

Answer (score 0):

```
FreeQ[\[PlusMinus]2, _PlusMinus]
```

Comment: What about clarifying the question?